# Azure Python: blob_service.set_blob_metadata(.....) deletes/overrides the last edited/set metadata(error)

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

with the following line of code I am setting **metadata1** to "**myblob**" blob:

```
blob_service.set_blob_metadata(container_name="mycontainer",
                               blob_name="myblob",
                               x_ms_meta_name_values={'metadata1': '1111'})
```

, but when I want to set another metadata, which is **metadata2**, on same blob, it **deletes** the last edited metadata which is "metadata1". Is there bug or am I doing something wrong???

```
blob_service.set_blob_metadata(container_name="mycontainer",
                               blob_name="myblob",
                               x_ms_meta_name_values={'metadata2': '2222'})
```

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior. From the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179414.aspx

> Optional. Sets a name-value pair for the blob.
>
> **Each call to this operation replaces all existing metadata attached to
>   the blob. To remove all metadata from the blob, call this operation
>   with no metadata headers.**
>
> Note that beginning with version 2009-09-19, metadata names must
>   adhere to the naming rules for C# identifiers.

What you would need to do is get the existing metadata first, make the changes and then set metadata again.

Comment: Why the names of metadata must obey the naming rules of  C# identifiers??

Comment: Why they need such a restriction? There must be a reason?

Comment: I don't know. You may want to post a comment on MSDN documentation link and ask the question there.

Comment: Even if you find somebody who can answer that - its not likely that this restriction is going to be changed; its something you have to deal with.

Comment: But there should be a standart. In Openstack Swift storage and Amazon S3 it is different. And there is no restriction like Azure